# Why are wave variables a and b normalized to sqrt(Z0) rather than just Z0?

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, transmission-line, wave, microwave

With reference to the equations below; why are the wave variables normalized to the root of the characteristic impedance rather than just the characteristic impedance itself?

[image: power wave variables]

equations sourced from: http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/ewa/ch14.pdf

Comment: Where did the formula come from and have you done any google research to try and understand this yourself?

Comment: Apologies, there was a pretty good answer in the document I posted that I had missed, I know this kind of thing annoys the people of here, my bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever we do the normalization it is done with some purpose. Here that purpose is simplifying power representation at different points in the two-port network. 
It is clearly mentioned in the 'Power Flow' section of the [same document](http://www.ece.rutgers.edu/~orfanidi/ewa/ch14.pdf) that you posted.

> One of the reasons for normalizing the traveling wave amplitudes by
>   \$\sqrt Z_0\$ in the definitions (14.1.4) was precisely this simple way of expressing the incident and reflected powers from a port.

so it eliminates the need for \$ Z_0\$ in power expression.

Another simple way to look at this is, usually, the power flow in any circuit is represented by terms similar to \$V^{2}/Z\$. Now in order to make power term independent of \$Z\$, you need to divide \$V\$ by \$\sqrt Z\$ and thereafter you will be able to simply analyze the circuit power by considering unit impedance.